# how to access the foreignkey value from a dict value in django

Tags: django

I am using foreignkey as my dropdown and I wanted to remove the dupicate values from my dropdown so I used query distinct(),but now i am getting dict values and I am not able to access my foreignkey value now. I am getting foreign key ID instead of string. I want to do something like

> for values in queryset:
> values.item_name.name

my models.py

```
class Requesition(models.Model):
    item_name = models.ForeignKey(Item,on_delete=models.CASCADE,limit_choices_to={'status':True})
    date = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    requested_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=1)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s--%s' % (self.item_name.item_name, self.item_name.specification)
```

my forms.py

```
class Purchase_order(forms.ModelForm):  
    products = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= Requesition.objects.all().select_related('item_name').values('item_name').distinct())
    class Meta:
        model = Purchase
        fields=('__all__')
        exclude = ('status','select','Total')
```

Comment: try ```values_list('item_name', flat=True)```

Comment: adding values_list('item_name', flat=True) gave me the values of ID but i wanted to get the name not ID, like using select_related.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by creating new method for [model manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/managers/#managers) that will do distinc and return results using two queries:

```py
# this goes inside your model manager class

def get_unique_by_item_name(self):
    item_ids = self.all().values('item_name').distinct()
    return self.filter(id__in=item_ids).select_related('item_name')
```

Then use this as form `queryset`:

```py
products = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= Requesition.objects.get_unique_by_item_name())
```